# Webpage ping when active

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web

I want a way for users to open this webpage, and whenever they are on that page, it updates the server that they are on the page. It should only work when the user is actually looking at the webpage (not inactive, like from switchings tabs). One way to do this which I have implemented is to keep pinging the server saying that I am alive.

This however causes a lot of load on the server and client side. I am using Google App Engine and webapp2, and was wondering if anyone knows a better way to do this.

Comment: don't think there is a a way to tell server that user is online witout pinging the server, if it's what you're asking

Comment: Well I know it has to ping the server at one point, but maybe theres a way to limit the number of times it must ping? The way I have implemented it is by sending a request to the server every 10 seconds and whenever the server hasn't seen a request for 10 seconds, it says the user is "not ready". This app is used by a lot of people simultaneously and I feel like it unnecessarily puts extra load on the server. Any ideas to optimize the process would be great.

Comment: Maybe every 20 seconds?! But either case it really depends on what you want and how much you are willing to pay for it :) but as already mentioned.. if you want to show presence you need to have a constant pinging of some sort..

Comment: You could use the channel API's "disconnected" POST sent when the browser closes the channel but I understand it's not totally reliable (i.e. no message is sent if the browsers crashes). No disconnect message = user still connected. Alternatively you could send a message down the channel asking the browser to ping (i.e. make a request of some sort) the server - no ping = disconnected.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, From what I have read, I think the best way is to simply ping the server. The other options seem to not be completely reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to ping the server while the user is online. Using other methods such as the Channel API with GAE proves to be unreliable since you are not constantly sending a ping message but rather just sending a disconnect message. If the browser crashes, no disconnect message is sent.

Comment: agree & disagree, mostly, these checks are for statistics, and if so: it wont matter losing even 15% of the samples... just keep in mind you should only take valid ones into account.